# tracking suspicious activity

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller

Recently, while managing an MVC app, I've been picking up some suspicious errors from unknown users (no user info in session cookies).

The errors include trying to visit subdirectories that don't exist (like '/YfcWZ/', '/user/login/', and '/wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType') as well as numerous invalid login attempts for unknown usernames.

It seems to me that someone (probably bitcoin miners) is trying to hack into our site. I altered my error logging to include the user's IP address with the following:

```
User = SessionSecurity.CurrentNameFromCookie() ?? Request.ServerVariables["X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
                                               ?? Request.UserHostAddress
```

But the IPs that have been logged are all `172.31.#.#` which are private intranet IPs.

Am I getting these internal IPs because the user is using VPN? Am I logging the IPs incorrectly? Is there a good way to block these sorts of 'attacks'? Is it not an attack at all, just an internal application error?

**EDIT**

I'm completely aware that other user's have asked questions to which the answer is "the client's IP address is in the X_FORWARDED_FOR server variable" ([Log client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457297/log-client-ip-address)). Hence why I'm accessing the X_FORWARDED_FOR variable when trying to get the user's IP. What I don't understand is why I'm still getting an internal IP even after accessing X_FORWARDED_FOR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log client IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457297/log-client-ip-address)

Comment: @Vulpex, not a duplicate.